# Jquery Tablesorter, sorting by link url rather than link content

Tags: tablesorter

I am using Tablesorter on a table which uses links in the first column (of 4). The problem is that in FF and Chrome it orders the first column when clicked by url not the content of the link. For example

```
<tr><td><a href="http://abc.com">zzz</a></td><td>11</td><td>22</td><td>33</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://cba.com">aaa</a></td><td>11</td><td>22</td><td>33</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://bbb.com">ccc</a></td><td>11</td><td>22</td><td>33</td></tr>
```

It will order

```
zzz
ccc
aaa
```

instead of alphabetical. Is this meant to be the case? Is there a fix anyone can suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I have got the same problem. Found solution in the [Documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html). Need to add a parser for the links which removes `<a>` tags from the beginning of the text in a column while sorting.

Here is code which should solve your problem:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id 
        id: 'links',
        is: function(s)
        {
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s)
        {
            // format your data for normalization 
            return s.replace(new RegExp(/<.*?>/),"");
        },
        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'text'
    }); 


    // Apply "links" parser to the appropriate column
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#MyTable").tablesorter({
            headers: {
                0: {
                    sorter: 'links'
                }
            }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean for auto-detected?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by inserting a span with style display:none before the link. In the span put the link text.

e.g.

```
<td><span style="display:none"><%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %></span>
                <a href='<%= Url.Action("Edit", new {id=item.Id}) %>'>
                    <%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %></a>
            </td>
```